# May the force be with you

Tags: translation

The official transition is:

> フォースと共にあれ

Can you break it down for me? What is あれ in this sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- フォース -- "the force"
- と -- the case particle "with~~"
- [共]{とも}に (noun 共 + particle に) -- adverbially, "together". ≂「[一緒]{いっしょ}に」. 「共に」 sounds more literary/stiff and less colloquial than 「一緒に」.
- あれ -- the imperative form (命令形) of the verb ある, meaning "to exist; to be".

So フォースと共にあれ literally means:

> "(imperative) Be/Exist together with the force."
>   i.e. "May you be with the force".
>   <sub>("May the force be with you" would literally be more like 「フォース**が**（あなたと）共にあれ・あらんことを」.)</sub>

(More colloquially it's like 「フォースと一緒にいろ・いなさい・いてください」)

Answer (score 3):

フォース　＝ 　force

と共に　　＝　[to be together with](https://bunpro.jp/grammar_points/291)

あれ is a conjugation of ある, which means "to have". So then, it means "May you have X".

I believe [this is a good explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/5zvg8d/%E4%BA%BA%E9%A1%9E%E3%81%AB%E6%A0%84%E5%85%89%E3%81%82%E3%82%8C_whats_that_%E3%81%82%E3%82%8C_doing_there/?st=jbqyq9i1&sh=ebe4f4fe) of the conjugation.

*May you have the force together with you.* → *May the force be with you.*